# CSS changes when pushing to Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, assets

I've tried a number of fixes for this issue with no success yet. I recently installed the CKEditor gem and had to do some configuring to the asset compiling settings, which could be throwing something off. My app works perfectly locally, but when I push to Heroku some of the CSS gets modified and when I inspect the page I see settings in the CSS called "code" that I didn't put there. This is from the inspector:

```
code {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #c7254e;
  background-color: #f9f2f4;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Some of my elements are now inheriting some of these attributes now. There are some divs that show up empty as well:

```
<code></code>
```

I'm sure it has to do with some sort of asset pipeline settings.

from my application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/*)

config.assets.precompile += [
  'styles.css.scss'
]
```

production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

This is in my javascripts for CKEditor configuration:

```
<%
 base_path = ''
 if ENV['PROJECT'] =~ /editor/i
  base_path << "/#{Rails.root.basename.to_s}/"
 end
 base_path << Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
 base_path << '/ckeditor/'
%>
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '<%= base_path %>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. When I began using CKEditor I couldn't just display my posts on my index page with

```
<%= post.body %>
```

because it would show all of the code on the page. Literally like this:

```
<p>My paragraph would be here</p>
```

I got around that by using this code:

```
<%= raw truncate(post.body, length: 800, :escape => false) %>
```

It works perfectly locally, but when I pushed to Heroku it caused odd behavior with any CSS that followed it when rendering the page. I need to read up on :escape some more to understand teh full effect that it's having on the page in production. I am able to just use:

```
<%= raw post.body %>
```

Which correctly displays the page, but doesn't truncate the body section, which is ultimately what I wanted. I'll try to figure that out separately.

EDIT: It's not the :escape that's effecting the page, it's the truncate method. I also tried post.body.html_safe.truncate(800) and raw post.body.truncate(800) with no success.